# Are there any signatures where the recid (v) is equal to 29,30 (or 33,34 compressed)?

Tags: ecdsa

Peter Wuille recently explained how ECDSA pubkey recovery is done, [in response to my question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38351/ecdsa-v-r-s-what-is-v).

So it's basically that for a given base64 signature, the value `v` in `v,r,s` provides the specific coordinates, hence the `recid` (recovery ID).

Example from [BitcoinCore test vectors](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/blob/master/bitcoin/tests/data/signmessage.json):

```
> sig =
> "H8PgOb/liZzt3QQHJn9kLBqH7E/i+SC6JTwYGtdNdOjnXzFqXnHMZqP7oZ1wb1QiQ3H/kF8xC9Yx7pK9ddlx8TA"
> addr = "1K5Z1nxN4mjUgCLpSXMRkeZxuAMpbn2CQB" wif =
> "KwfJTiKdcjNMjBu4ksgGd21EZXz6JomoZNbirP3nfd3K9ZMXMEUi"
> 
> v,r,s = vrs = (31,
> 88597177789312009809148107221292570613390338668815747761545214128303675599079L,
> 43057030252916568867525408201971649068117337291455262356277580652864892694832L)
```

The value of v is `27 + recid` for uncompressed keys and `31 + recid` for compressed keys.

Ive run a Python loop using [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) which signs a message using a random key, and I've yet to ever see `v=29` or `v=30`. Why is this? Is it by design, or is it just a very low probability event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For random signatures, it is an extremely low probability event. Around 1 in 2<sup>128</sup>, so it will likely never ever actually happen.

However, you can easily construct a valid signature that has one of those, and the recovery algorithm will give you an actual public key for it. It just won't be a public key anyone actually knows the secret key for.