# Representation of coordinates in signature. OpenSSL

Tags: signature, source-code, openssl

I want to calculate the **v**-value from the signature obtained using the OpenSSL [ECDSA_do_sign](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/4ace4ccda2934d2628c3d63d41e79abe041621a7/include/openssl/ec.h#L1178) function. I found that this value is calculated using the parity of **y**-coordinate of **r**. [Here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38351/ecdsa-v-r-s-what-is-v) I also found that the parity of **y** is equal to the parity of **r**. I want to understand whether it depends on the implementation. Can anyone tell exactly how the coordinates **x** and **y** are stored inside **r** in OpenSSL. I can't find it in the code.

**edited:**
  I understand how v is calculated. My question is how to get the **y**-coordinate of **r** in the specific implementation of ECDSA in the OpenSSL library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `r` is just a number and doesn't explicitly store or encode any point coordinates.  In a signature, `r` is set to the X coordinate of the point `R`, which is really `k*G`, where `k` is the secret nonce used during signing, then reduced mod the curve order.
In secp256k1, this *usually* means that `r` is in fact the X coordinate (because `r` itself is usually very big), but it is not always so.

During verification, the verifier attempts to reconstruct the original `R` point by from the signature values `(s, r)`, the message `z` and the signer's public key `P` by solving the equation `s*R' = z*G + r*P`, then reduce the X coordinate of `R'` mod the curve order and check that it is equal to `r` given in the signature.

I've never used openssl, but the process seems to be in `ossl_ecdsa_verify_sig()`.  So you can see `R'` being computed here :
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/ec/ecdsa_ossl.c#L396-L404

After these lines, the reduction mod the order is done and finally the equality test.  In simple signature verification, the Y coordinate of `R'` is not used, but it is available from the value `point` (which is `R'`) in openssl's implementation.

edit:
Also, I just realized I should add a something about pubkey recovery since you mention the `v` or `recid` value in your question.
When doing pubkey recovery from message and signature (as in the case when the signer's pukey is not given), to get the Y coordinate from a possible `R'` point, you would try a few values based on `r` as the candidate X coordinates.

The possible X coordinates of `R'` will be `r` itself, or `r + curve_order` (and both can be valid X's).  You can then solve the curve's equation `y^2 = x^3 + 7` to get the possible Y values for each.